# Code outputting html instead of an image?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the code that I am referring to:

```
<?php if ( is_archive() ) { echo '<img src="'.bloginfo('template_url').'/images/test.png" />'; }?>
```

This is what the code outputs: `http://site.com/wp-content/themes/themename`

I'd like it to output the actual image in the code. What part of this did I overlook?

Comment: Can you be more specific.  The current code will output the `<img src="whateverurl/image/test.png" />`

Comment: The code you have written isn't going to output what you say it does. It's either going to output an image tag or nothing

Comment: That's very strange. On my screen, it's showing exactly what I put up there. I was thinking there may possibly be an error in the code but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Oh yes. It shows that because bloginfo  actually echo's the output . it doesnt return string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bloginfo()` doesn't output the string. It echo's it directly to output stream.
So, the code should be:

```
<?php if ( is_archive() ) { ?>
   <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/test.png" />'; 
<?php  }  ?>
```

Or else,  you can use `get_bloginfo()` :

```
<?php if ( is_archive() ) { echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/test.png" />'; }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$template_url = get_bloginfo('template_url');

<?php if ( is_archive() ) { echo '<img src="'.$template_url.'/images/test.png" />'; } ?>
```

Comment: You can't use this. If you want to store values from  bloginfo into variables , you are supposed to use `get_bloginfo()`  not `bloginfo()`

Comment: I've already given the answer.  No need to edit it to the correct code.